# ImportError: cannot import name get_content_type when trying to import soundcloud

Tags: python, importerror

I'm trying to use the [Soundcloud-Python](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python) Library to utilize the Soundcloud API. I installed it as I was instructed to using `pip install soundcloud` and I had no errors reported. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Error Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploadToSoundcloud.py", line 1, in <module>
    import soundcloud
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from soundcloud.client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 5, in <module>
    from soundcloud.request import make_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/request.py", line 14, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.filepost import get_content_type, iter_fields
ImportError: cannot import name get_content_type
```

Code:

```
import soundcloud

client = soundcloud.Client(
    client_id='f3ddcf1f3e069b44a21115d0d58d6005',
    client_secret='**censored**',
    username='**censored**',
    password='**censored**'
)

print client.get('/me').username
```

Comment: Do you have another dependent package `requests` installed? If not, do `pip install requests` and then try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug caused by a mismatch in the version of requests and soundcloud-python. I just pushed an update to PyPi. Try installing / upgrading with pip install --upgrade soundcloud and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks so much! [Hoorah](https://twitter.com/WillemLabu/status/384649359427506177)!

Comment: getting the same error. upgrade says: Requirement already up-to-date for soundcloud, fudge==1.0.3, requests>=0.14.0, simplejson>=2.0 but still same error.